# Just installed NVIDIA restricted driver for Ubuntu and now my Macbook Pro (6,2) only boots to CLI

Tags: macbook-pro, nvidia-graphics-card, ubuntu-10.10

I just installed NVIDIA restricted driver for Ubuntu and now my Macbook Pro (6,2) only boots to CLI.  Any ideas why this might be the case?  Also, how can I get my GUI back?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to boot using the `recovery mode` option, then run the safe-mode X session.  Once you start that, you will be given an option to reconfigure your X configuration.  Create a new X configuration, then reboot.